# Sum list values within a given range using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to sum the values of a list, but only if list values are within a specific range (for example *between 5 and -4*,  or *<= 0*)

- Use a `while` loop to solve this.
- Don't use additional lists.

The code doesn't work if I use *is smaller than* within the statement to check list values.

Where am I going wrong while using "<"?

My example data:

```
# list
ulis = [ 5 , 4 , 4 , 3 , 1 , -2 , -3 , -5 , -7 , -7 ]
 #e      0   1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8    9

# list length
ulis_l  = len (ulis)

# to count total
total_1 = 0

# index nr list
e       = 0

# list of numbers used for total 
lprt    = []
```

Using `while` with `> = 0`; this works:

```
print ( " # while command in progress " )
while ( ulis[e] >= 0) and ( e < ulis_l ):   
    total_1 = total_1 + ulis [e]
    lprt.append (ulis [e])
    e = e + 1
    print (total_1)
```

The same code, with `>= 0` changed to `<= 0` doesn't work, and I don't understand what is happening:

```
print ( " # while command in progress " )
while ( ulis[e] <= 0) and ( e < ulis_l ):
    total_1 = total_1 + ulis [e]
    lprt.append (ulis [e])
    e = e + 1
    print (total_1)
```

I used this code to check the output:

```
print ( " " )
print ( " " )
print ( " # Total sum " )
print (total_1)
print ( " " )
print ( " # values used form org list ulis for Total sum " )
print (lprt)
print ( " " )
print ( " # ulis n org values " )
print ( ulis_l )
```

For the first loop, this is printed:

```
 # while command in progress 
5
9
13
16
17


 # Total sum
17

 # values used form org list ulis for Total sum
[5, 4, 4, 3, 1]

 # ulis n org values
10
```

but for the second loop I see:

```
 # while command in progress 


 # Total sum
0

 # values used form org list ulis for Total sum
[]

 # ulis n org values
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `while`, it *stops at the first false result*. Your loop doesn't work because the first value you test is greater than zero, and so the condition for the loop is not met:

```
>>> ulis[0] <= 0
False
```

You don't want to *stop* the loop when a value should not be added to the total. You want to ignore that value and continue to the next value. If you *must* use a `while` loop, then use a separate test in an `if` statement:

```
while e < ulis_l:
    if ulis[e] <= 0:
        # You can use += here instead of total_1 = total_1 + ...
        total_1 += ulis[e]
        lprt.append(ulis[e])
    e = e + 1
    print(total_1)
```

That's because you want to visit *every value* in the `ulis` list to test if they need to be included. Here is a demo of the above loop:

```
>>> ulis = [5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7, -7]
>>> ulis_l = len(ulis)
>>> e = total_1 = 0
>>> lprt = []
>>> while e < ulis_l:
...     if ulis[e] <= 0:
...         # You can use += here instead of total_1 = total_1 + ...
...         total_1 += ulis[e]
...         lprt.append(ulis[e])
...     e = e + 1
...     print(total_1)
...
0
0
0
0
0
-2
-5
-10
-17
-24
>>> total_1
-24
>>> lprt
[-2, -3, -5, -7, -7]
```

It is better, and easier, to use a [`for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) for this, you can loop directly over the values in a list:

```
for value in ulis:
    if value <= 0:
        lprt.append(value)
        total_1 += value
        print(total_1)
```

I moved the `print()` call into the test, so it only prints when a valid value i found:

```
>>> lprt, total_1 = [], 0
>>> for value in ulis:
...     if value <= 0:
...         lprt.append(value)
...         total_1 += value
...         print(total_1)
...
-2
-5
-10
-17
-24
```

If all you want to do is sum a series of values that match specific criteria, you can also put a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) inside a function call, using the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
total_1 = sum(value for value in ulis if value <= 0)
```

This is a more compact expression for the same result:

```
>>> sum(value for value in ulis if value <= 0)
-24
```

Your first example worked because the input is sorted in *descending order*; the first value that's smaller than 0 (-2) can *only* be followed by more values that are lower than 0. If your input is large, it can be quite a smart idea to limit the number of iterations this way. You don't need a `while` loop for this however, you can just use the [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
# first loop, values greater than 0
for value in ulis:
    if value <= 0:
        # input is sorted in descending order,
        # so all remaining values _will_ be smaller.
        # To save time, we can end the loop early.
        break

    # only sums values greater than 0
    total_1 += value
    lprt.append(value)
```

If you want to make use of this property for your `<= 0` loop, then you need to change the order in which you iterate the list. You can do this with the [`reversed()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) here:

```
# second loop, summing values smaller than or equal to 0 
for value in reversed(ulis):
    if value > 0:
        # input is iterated over in ascending order,
        # so all remaining values _will_ be greater than zero.
        # To save time, we can end the loop early.
        break

    # only sums values smaller than or equal to 0
    total_1 += value
    lprt.append(value)
```

When you add a `print()` to the latter version, you can see that the values are added up in reverse order:

```
>>> lprt, total_1 = [], 0
>>> for value in reversed(ulis):
...     if value > 0:
...         break
...     total_1 += value
...     lprt.append(value)
...     print(total_1)
...
-7
-14
-19
-22
-24
>>> lprt
[-7, -7, -5, -3, -2]
```

If you need to have `lprt` in the correct, forward order, you can reverse the ordering again by taking the full slice with negative index:

```
lprt = lprt[::-1]   # reverse the lprt list
```

If you have *two* criteria, like *the value is between 5 and -4*, and the input list is *very large* but still sorted, then you could consider using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the start and end indices of your input list, then use the [`range()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) to generate the indices between those two points. The standard library provides the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for this.

Note that this does mean the values have to be sorted in *ascending* order, not descending.

Take into account that `range()` treats the `stop` index as not included in the indices that are produced, so if you test for `value >= -4` and `value <= 5`, then you want to use `bisect.bisect_right()` to find the first index where the values would all be greater than 5:

```
import bisect

# ascending order! ulis = ulis[::-1] 

start_index = bisect.bisect_left(ulis, -4)  # values >= -4
stop_index = bisect.bisect_right(ulis, 5)  # value <= 5

total_1 = sum(ulis[index] for index in range(start_index, stop_index))
```

Comment: It really helped me to understand the function a lot better.
Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

This condition is never true: `ulis[e] <= 0`
You used `and`, so both conditions (`( ulis[e] <= 0)` and `( e < ulis_l )`) must be true. The first condition will never be true.
This problem is not related to jupyter nootbook.